# ERROR [main] util.ServerCommandLine: Failed to stop all non-daemon threads, so terminating JVM

Tags: hadoop, hbase

My question is about hbase.

When I shut down the **HBase2.4.9** cluster.

I got a weird anomaly.

one **RegionServer** throw exception :

```
2022-02-23 09:38:46,356 INFO  [main] util.Threads: Non daemon thread hconnection-0x14049c09-shared-pool-1973 is still alive
2022-02-23 09:38:46,356 INFO  [main] util.Threads:
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-02-23 09:38:46,356 INFO  [main] util.Threads: Non daemon thread hconnection-0x14049c09-shared-pool-1974 is still alive
2022-02-23 09:38:46,357 INFO  [main] util.Threads:
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-02-23 09:38:46,357 ERROR [main] util.ServerCommandLine: Failed to stop all non-daemon threads, so terminating JVM
2022-02-23 09:38:46,360 INFO  [shutdown-hook-0] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook starting; hbase.shutdown.hook=true; fsShutdownHook=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$ClientFinalizer@30331109
2022-02-23 09:38:46,360 INFO  [shutdown-hook-0] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Starting fs shutdown hook thread.
```

Comment: I looked at the source code and found a fix for this problem ：https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-26468   this is issues leads to ERROR

Comment: why hconection is not exit

Answer (score 0):

issues:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-26468

why hconnection-xxx  is not exit ?

I looked the log and found phoenix connection

```
INFO  [pool-65-thread-1] util.QueryUtil: Creating connection with the jdbc url: jdbc:phoenix:hd01,hd02,hd03:2181:/hbase;
```

jstack :

```
"hconnection-0x4e8c0fac-shared-pool-2205" #6260 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0ea00f3000 nid=0xdea waiting on condition [0x00007f0e6dce1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e4470860> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The corresponding stack is printed whenever a connection is created

So it was the phoenix connection  bring about

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).